# Dropbox sync bandwidth is it limited?

Tags: dropbox

I have installed dropbox python client for linux and I noticed the sync bandwidth is quite limited:

```
$ dropbox status
Syncing (252,088 files remaining, 18 days left)
Downloading 252,088 files (35.1 KB/sec, 18 days left)
```

Is there a way to make it faster?

Note: Yes I have a 100Mbit/s internet connexion...

Comment: Maybe it's because of many small files are syncing. Test with a large size file and see speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check if there is a 75% cap enabled, as [mentioned here](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/26)

If there isn't then it's probably your Internet, try switching to a different network source (from wireless to wired) or use a different Internet connection. I had the same issue before and it was solved by changing to a different Internet connection, yes I have 100Mbit/s too but it didn't help.

**Alternatively**

If you already have another synced up dropbox, just copy the files over to the new install of Dropbox, if you're just trying to get the initial sync done.

**Also** [take a look at LAN Sync, a feature in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/137)

This honestly isn't a SO question because is isn't really a programming question, a forum like [Superuser.com might be better suited perhaps.](https://superuser.com/)

**edit:** saw that you already have a superuser account, my bad. :)

Comment: Well, I have to admit, I first wanted to post on superuser then I checked the amount of questions related to Dropbox for both SO and SU... I chose the obscure side...

Comment: Concerning your link, Almost everything on Drobox website is related to the desktop version of Dropbox. The command-line tool is a bit too simple.

Comment: @coin ah I see, so you don't want to use their GUI? I just checked the CLI, there isn't much, other than lansync option, it's pretty limited as you said. I'm sure there's a config file somewhere, i'm trying to look for it xD

Comment: I'm getting happy: `$ dropbox status
Syncing (137,855 files remaining, 12 hrs left)
Downloading 137,855 files (6,115 KB/sec, 12 hrs left)`

Comment: @coin sweet! as far as the command line goes, I couldn't find a config file that lets you change or value or something, it's probably inside a db, so no dice. if you want to do all the stuff that a gui can, i think using ssh into the machine and installing a window manager/x11 is the way to go.. good luck!